# Master Document Formatting

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to create a master document with several subdocuments; however, when I open the master document as a whole, the formatting changes for each subdocument and is different from that in the original subdocument files (example: fonts are changed, words are not bolded that should be, etc).

How do I get the master document to keep the formatting of each of the individual subdocuments?

Also, when I try to edit the formatting, click save, then re-open, it does not keep the changes.

Comment: If you open sub documents individually, will they still show their original format?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:

Probably the master styles are being imposed. Try to create new styles giving them different names on subdocuments and apply those styles on subdocuments.